# How to make this Conceptual Dependency direction symbol in LaTex?

Tags: stacking-symbols

[image: Conceptual Dependency Direction]

I've tried several approaches using large brackets and arrows but can't get them to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that you look for picture? Please, show a code, with which you try  solve your problem.

Comment: It is impossible to tell even how big this is supposed to be. Is it part of a larger diagram or equation? We who do not use such symbols regularly depend on you to put these concepts in a broader context....

Answer (score 1):

A `pstricks` solution::

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \psset{linewidth=0.6pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, arrowsize=2pt 2.5, angleB=180, linejoin=1}
     \pnodes(-1.5,0){C}(0,0){D} \pnode(0,-1){B’}\pnode(3,1){A}\pnode(3,-1){B}
    \ncline{D}{C}\ncangle[angleA=90]{D}{A}
    \psset{arrows=-}
    \ncangle[angleA=-90]{D}{B}
    \psline[ ArrowInside=-<, ArrowInsidePos=0.95](B’)(B)
    \nput[labelsep=2ex]{135}{D}{D}
    \nput{180}{C}{Some text}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great! 
How can I modify it so that I can add text centered at the end of each arrow?

Comment: To add text near a node, use the command `\nput{angle}{node name}{text}`. Please see my updated answer. For details see the documentation of `pst-node`.

Answer (score 0):

For help to you for design own MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations,decorations.markings,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>  = {Stealth[]},
decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow{>}}}
                        ]
\draw[postaction={decorate},->]    (1,0) -| (0,1) -- (1,1);
\draw[->]   (0,0.5) node [above left] {D} -- + (-1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above code gives:

[image]